# Diagnosing a gun leaking gas

Tags: equipment, airsoft, maintenance

**Gun:**

Colt 1911 Cybergun 100th anniversary

My Colt 1911 Cybergun is leaking gas either from its magazine or its own valve.
I only have one Magazine so cant check if its a mag issue.

**Description of Problem:**

When you pull the trigger to fire a BB the gun barrel goes back (Blowback) but gets stuck there, then the gun gets very cold due to the gas leaking. The Magazine will then be too cold to touch.

Any solutions on how to find the problem (other than buy a new magazine)?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience that is mostly likely a Nozzle issue. One way to tell if your mag is leaking; Fill your mag up all the way then stick it in a bowl of water. If no bubbles start emerging from the mag it is leak free. If they do, you know where the leak is and will have to replace the O ring in that area. Based on the other things you said, you can 1. Make sure to clean and relube your gun, if you are lucky this might fix it, and make sure to do this regularly. If that doesn't help, my next idea would be a cracked nozzle, in which you will have to buy a replacement part. Try to inspect the nozzle and see if you can identify any cracks anywhere on it. If you want more detailed answers, try going to www.reddit.com/r/airsoft/ and make a post, but make sure to read the the rules first. If you wanna PM me personally, contact /u/The_Mexx and I should respond within 24 hours. I hope this help you!